# Adding Polyline to map using coordinates array

Tags: arrays, swift, mkmapview, polyline

What's the best way of adding a `Polyline` on the map using an array of coordinates? (Got from Firebase)

At the moment I have an array `latitudeCoordinates` and an array of `longitudeCoordinates`
for now I'll say `latitudeCoordinates = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]` &  `longitudeCoordinates = [-4.4, -5.5, -6.6]`

Would I try to concatenate the arrays so `coordinatesTogether` equals *lat, long, lat, long* etc...
(If so, how)

or could I create a Polyline where it takes the arrays and does it automatically?

Comment: zip + map should do the trick to have an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D `: `let coordinates = zip(latitudeCoordinates, longitudeCoordinates).map{ CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0, longitude: $1) }`

Comment: @Larme That's it! Thank you so much!